# How to make the most out of operations?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile

Currently for the operations I send my 3 main heroes out for the longest period when I go to sleep/work. This means they're away for a while but earn more XP and coins per operation. However, as they're away for a while I am unable to use them for fighting for a while.

How can I use operations to get the most out of my heroes and get the most coins? Is sending them on 4 3 hour operations better or worse then 1 12 hour one?

Answer (score 2):

Longer duration ops are always a better return for the time. Going on higher Ops levels increases the chance of gem drops.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 minutes every half an hour or hour I would go for the lowest duration ones (although you can receive better equipment and more money for the longer ops you still have the same "drop" chance for gems, so more ops means more chances)